# In mysql how do I only search through the first 10 records

Tags: mysql, database

I am writing a query, but I only want to search the first 10 records in the table. I know that in a select limit usually limits the records, but it doesn't work for this instance.
eg

```
SELECT * FROM `logon` WHERE `username`='superman' ORDER BY `user_id` LIMIT 10
```

The above line will never work because the query only returns one.

I only want to search through the first 10 records, and limit doesn't work in this case.

So how do I limit my search to the first 10 records?

Comment: use `subquery`.

Comment: how do you define "first"?

Comment: Well the first 10 records. Say there is a 100 records I only want to search the first 10 records. I suppose if you mean order, it would be the first 10 user  ids. I think I can use ORDER By for that.

Comment: Hi Chirag can you show me how to do this with a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `logon` ORDER BY `user_id` LIMIT 10) as temp
WHERE temp.`username`='superman';
```

Comment: though correct per OP but having simple `select * from where condition order by sort limit col` would be faster than this if Op has right index on the filter column

Answer (score 0):

Use order by

```
SELECT * FROM `logon` WHERE `username` = 'superman' ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets - so LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: No like does the closest match. I want the exact match, but I only want to search the first 10 records in the table as the username is unique anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a subquery which returns the "first" 10 records and put a where clause on the result set.

Comment: Something like:
Select * from (select * from table order by column limit 10)t where t.col2 = $value

Comment: Yes that might work. Going to see if it does the job

Comment: Even though you gave me the correct answer I have to give it to Keyur as he gave a more complete answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: Not an issue. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `logon` 
WHERE `username`='superman' 
and user_id in (select user_id from logon order by user_id limit 10)
```

(I haven't tried this, but I *think* it's the fastest way to do this)

Comment: Per OP this is the right answer and even I would do the same but doing it is meaningless ...

Comment: This looked like the neatest solution, but it give an error #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 0):

Not the right Way...but can be done...

SELECT *
FROM `logon`
WHERE `username`='superman' AND srno BETWEEN 1 AND 10;